# Is join() enough for clean up python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, urllib3

I've worked around with a multithreading `client` calls a domain with several HTTP requests once a minute. Basically each HTTP is wrapped in a single thread in the client. The `connection class` uses `urllib3` with a connection pool to manage sockets and reuse them. The `connection class` does not support `asyncio`.

But sometimes, usually after a long time running the `client` (~24hrs), some `OSError: Too many open files` will be raised in the `connection class` when sending the requests. And usually those exception was captured in threads with id greater than 100k... So I am thinking my way of manipulating threads is totally wrong.

The sample code shows as below.

```
def run():
  timer_start = time.time()
  workers = []
  # create several tasks in workers
  # i.e. workers.append(threading.Thread(target=foo, ...)
  run_workers(workers)
  timer = Time(timer_start - time.time() + 60, run)
  timer.start()

def run_workers(workers):
  i = 0
  while i < len(workers):
    if threading.active_count() < 8:
      workers[i].start()
      i += 1
    else:
      time.sleep(0.1)
  i = 0
  while len(workers):
    if i > len(workers):
      i = 0
    workers[i].join(timeout=0.1)
    if not workers[i].is_alive():
      del workers[i]
    i += 1

# A foo might do behavior like this
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
  res = pool.urlopen('POST', kwargs[url], kwargs[body], ...)
  if not (200 <= res.status < 300):
    #raise_error(...)    

#main()
run()
```

My main question will be is my method good enough for cleaning up finished threads in a long run client? I think python recycle used threads id but why would I still get a thread running with id > 100k? Does that mean those already finished threads still hanging there?